# Issue with nested variables

Tags: powershell

The script is self-explanitory but I have no idea how to get it to work. I want to figure out how to pass the variable `$ComputerPath` to the function and in that script set `$ComputerPath`

```
Function CheckPath {
    While (!$args[0]) {
        Write-Host "`nVariable Undefined"
        $Args[0] = Read-Host "Enter Valid Path"
    } 
    while (!(test-path $Args[0])) {
        Write-Host "Unable To Location Files, Please Check Again."
        $args[0] = Read-Host "Enter Valid Path"
    }
}

$ComputersPath = "missingfile.txt"

$ComputersPath
CheckPath $ComputersPath
$ComputersPath
```

My Result

```
PS Z:\Powershell Scripting\Test Lab> .\TestFunction.ps1
missingfile.txt
Unable To Location Files, Please Check Again.
Enter Valid Path: log.txt
missingfile.txt
PS Z:\Powershell Scripting\Test Lab>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try pass the variabable to function like this:

```
CheckPath $ComputersPath
```

`$` in single quote is see by powershell as literar 'dollar sign' and not a variable qualifier

And change these lines:

```
$args[0] = Read-Host "Enter Valid Path"
CheckPath
```

in

```
CheckPath (Read-Host "Enter Valid Path")
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
Function CheckPath {    
    IF (!$args[0]) {    
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "Variable Undefined"
        $args[0] = Read-Host "Enter Valid Path"
    }
    else
    {
      "Found"
      $global:ComputersPath  = $args[0]
    }

IF (!(Test-Path ($Args[0]))) {
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Unable To Location Files, Please Check Again."
    CheckPath (Read-Host "Enter Valid Path")
}
```

}

Edit:

To set whatever variable you use in the function I give you a example:

```
function test 
{   
    $myvar = $MyInvocation.line.split(' ')[1].replace('$','')    
    "`$$myvar value now is $($args[0])"

    Invoke-Expression  "`$global:$myvar = 'yahoo'"    

    "{0} value now is {1}" -f "`$$myvar", (invoke-expression "`$$myvar")
}
```

after you can try this:

```
PS C:\ps> $a="google" #or whatever variable you want...
PS C:\ps> test $a
$a value now is google
$a value now is yahoo
PS C:\ps> $a
yahoo
```

Now you can use the code in this function and put in your `CheckPath function` based on the logic of your goal

Comment: Attempted changes but still no avail. Been playing with this for like 4 hours and no luck >.>

Comment: Tried both, and they both work except they won't update the variable.

Comment: @user1451070 You can add the `else` like in my answer. And... it'snt necessary modify  your original post based on the answer provided to you beacuse make question and answer less readable... thank you.

Comment: That contradicts my goal, i intend to call this function for each of the variables that I will be testing via this function. If i add the ComputersPath it will be of a mute point.

Comment: Set whatever variable is inputted into the function. I want to set the variable to whatever is entered into the function.

I am trying to create a dynamic function so if i call CheckPath $variable1
it will run the function $Variable1 in the function and if need be adjust the value of $Variable1 as needed. The line `$global:ComputersPath  = $args[0]` does to what i need it to, but i want to be able to set any variable i enter into the function.

Comment: @user1451070 I've added an example in my answer. You need to add this logic in your code. Based on your necessity.

Comment: Went through all my old posts and accepted all the answers that were legit answers still nno answers for several questions

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no need to cast $args[0] to a string. second, you're passing $ComputersPath inside single quotes. Single quotes prevent variable expansion and the value is passed as is, literally.

Give this a try:

```
Function CheckPath {

    IF (!$args[0]) {
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "Variable Undefined"
        $args[0] = Read-Host "Enter Valid Path"
    } 

    IF (!(Test-Path $Args[0])) 
    {
        Write-Host "`nUnable To Location Files, Please Check Again."
        $args[0] = Read-Host "Enter Valid Path"
        CheckPath
    }

    $args[0]
}



CheckPath $ComputersPath
```

Here's a more robust way to prompt the user indefinitely in case the path provided doesn't exist:

```
do{
    [string]$path = Read-Host "Enter a valid path"
} while ( -not (test-path $path) )

$path
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define the parameter within the function, and declare it as mandatory.

```
Function CheckPath {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Path 
    )#End Param

    while (!(test-path $Path)) {
        Write-Host "Unable To Location Files, Please Check Again."
        $Path = Read-Host "Enter Valid Path"
    } #End While
    write-output $path
} #End Function
```

This will still force the user to input a path file, but makes the code look cleaner imho.  When I tested this, I got the results you were asking for.  I do like Shay Levi's method of prompting the user. Using his example it would look like this:

```
Function CheckPath {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Path 
    )#End Param

    do{
        [string]$path = Read-Host "Enter a valid path"
    } while ( -not (test-path $path) )
    write-output $path
}
```